# Angular prod build error in Cannot assign to a reference or variable

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli

I can't build prod version of my angular app.

And have only this message in IDE console:

> ERROR in Cannot assign to a reference or variable!

So I can build only if add these options:

```
--aot=false --buildOptimizer=false
```

But, even with these options app fails after deploy with this message in browser console:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined

which can be [fixed](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/950) by adding one more option:

```
--optimization=false
```

---

When I try to build with

```
npm run ng build -- --prod
```

I have a log file with some information:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Backend\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\USER_NAME\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'ng',
1 verbose cli   'build',
1 verbose cli   '--',
1 verbose cli   '--prod' ]
2 info using npm@6.10.2
3 info using node@v10.15.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'preng', 'ng', 'postng' ]
5 info lifecycle dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2~preng: dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2
6 info lifecycle dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2~ng: dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2
7 verbose lifecycle dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2~ng: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2~ng: PATH: C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\DEV\WebStormProjects\dont-play-with-gp-web\node_modules\.bin;C:\DEV\WebStormProjects\dont-play-with-gp-web\node_modules\.bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Backend\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.5\jre64;C:\Backend\PostgreSQL\10\bin;C:\Backend\nodejs;C:\Backend\WinSCP\;C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
9 verbose lifecycle dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2~ng: CWD: C:\DEV\WebStormProjects\dont-play-with-gp-web
10 silly lifecycle dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2~ng: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'ng "build" "--prod"' ]
11 silly lifecycle dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2~ng: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2~ng: Failed to exec ng script
13 verbose stack Error: dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2 ng: `ng "build" "--prod"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:326:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2
15 verbose cwd C:\DEV\WebStormProjects\dont-play-with-gp-web
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Backend\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\USER_NAME\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "ng" "build" "--" "--prod"
18 verbose node v10.15.3
19 verbose npm  v6.10.2
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2 ng: `ng "build" "--prod"`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2 ng script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I tried to update everything, but it doesn't help.

Here is result of `ng version`:

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.4
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.4
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.4
@angular/cdk                      8.2.0
@angular/cli                      8.3.4
@angular/flex-layout              8.0.0-beta.27
@angular/material                 8.2.0
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.4
@schematics/angular               8.3.4
@schematics/update                0.803.4
rxjs                              6.5.3
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

And my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "dont-play-with-gp-web",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.6",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "8.0.0-beta.27",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.6",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.6",
    "angular-markdown-editor": "^2.0.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-markdown": "^8.1.0",
    "ngx-material-file-input": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
    "@types/node": "~12.7.5",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~5.20.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  }
}
```

So, what can I do in this case? How to find a reason for error and how to fix it?

If it can help - there is my source code:

https://bitbucket.org/mohaxspb/gp-web/commits/tag/ATTEMPT_TO_FIX_PROD_BUILD_WITH_DEPS_UPDATE

---

Same question on `ru.stackoverflow`: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1025395

---

**SOVLED:**

At last I have error reason (SO user https://stackoverflow.com/users/10123947/shadow found it): there were attempt to change value of variable in template, defined in template with help of self-made directive.

Problem here is in poor error message. Mentioned user received details only via debugging compiler (as I understand). There are some details (in Russian): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1025417/17609

**UPDATE:**

I add issues and PRs to angular repository to fix it.

1. No details in error message: [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32759), [PR](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/32760)
2. Assigning value to template variable crashes prod build: [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32761), [PR](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/32762)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It happened that most exceptions from the AST parser are a headache. Just because they don't carry anything useful, except for just a message:

> ERROR in Cannot assign to a reference or variable!

Oh really?

For example, the linker (`ViewBuilder`) always writes the place where it cannot build template expressions.

Googling is probably one of the solutions. But the whole circle will be closed on the fact that most answers will offer to check the `ngModel` directive usage in template.

---

The second option is a little bit hardcode. It’s worth getting into the compiler itself and debug. Angular uses `node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js` during compilation.

Let's open this file and try to search the text `Cannot assign to a reference or variable!`. We will find the `_AstToIrVisitor` class and the `visitPropertyWrite` method. There is such a line of code

```
// Otherwise it's an error.
throw new Error('Cannot assign to a reference or variable!');
```

The exception is thrown without any information at all

Let's add the `console.log(ast)` before the exception, where `ast` is the parameter of the `visitPropertyWrite` function. The parser will log an instance of the `PropertyWrite` class to the console:

```
PropertyWrite {
  span: ParseSpan { start: 0, end: 73 },
  receiver: ImplicitReceiver { span: ParseSpan { start: 0, end: 0 } },
  name: 'translation',
  value: MethodCall {
    span: ParseSpan { start: 14, end: 73 },
    receiver: ImplicitReceiver { span: [ParseSpan] },
    name: 'getTranslationForLanguageFromArticle',
    args: [ [PropertyRead], [PropertyRead] ]
  }
}
```

We came to the conclution that we have to understand that relationship between the `translation` property and the `getTranslationForLanguageFromArticle` method call. As I attempted to clone your example from Bitbucket I looked for the "getTranslationForLanguageFromArticle" usage and found this line in the `feed.component.html`:

```
(change)="translation = getTranslationForLanguageFromArticle($event.value, article)"
```

This is what the parser cannot understand as `translation` is not a class property. It's a local `ng-template` variable accessed implicitly in the `*ngVar` directive.

I would create some method like `changeTranslation` inside the component and do manipulations with `article.translations[indexOfCorrectArticleTranslation(article)]` there.

At least you know which way to go :)

Comment: I found a way to use my directive and do not ruin prod build. But this needs to edit compiler script [here](https://github.com/angular/compiler-builds/blob/6eaf2806247d295da17de900d66059932f23923a/src/compiler_util/expression_converter.js#L489)

Comment: There is check for type of expression in template `if (localExpr instanceof ReadPropExpr)` and, if add one more condition `|| localExpr instanceof ReadVarExpr)` everything is OK (prod build succeeded, so as deploy and run in browser). I'll try tomorrow to create pull request to compiler with example. Also there is a way to provide more info in [error](https://github.com/angular/compiler-builds/blob/6eaf2806247d295da17de900d66059932f23923a/src/compiler_util/expression_converter.js#L500) by adding `JSON.stringify(ast)` to error message.

Comment: This helped us to find some binding mistake, thank you very much for the detailed explanation!

Comment: The second options worked well for me. In my case, the problem was a two-way data bind [(property)] without the propertyChange output in the child component.

Answer (score 3):

If I may add... I got this error, when I named the template-control the same as a binding property of my class. Like this:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="passwordConfirmation" #passwordConfirmation="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="passwordConfirmation"/>
```

"passwordConfirmation" is the name of the control in the template AND the name of the property/variable of the component class. This seems to be confusing for the compiler as it tries to bind to the template variable instead of the class property.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like one of the names of the variable that was giving problem, it's really hard to assume which one is giving the problem and time consuming the debug this for anybody here. I suggest you check all `ngIf`, `ngModel`, `ngFor`, etc... most likely you're trying to use the same name of the variable at someplace in your project.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I'll try to find something like that. Now I try to remove all component and it helps - prod build succeeded. So I'll try to add components until they break build.

Comment: At last I have error reason (SO user https://stackoverflow.com/users/10123947/shadow found it): there were attempt to change value of variable in template, defined in template with help of self-made directive.

Problem here is in poor error message. Mentioned user received details only via debugging compiler (as I understand). There are some details (in Russian): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1025417/17609

Comment: yes, as said I suggest to you just commented out the sections which have `ngIf`, `ngModel`, `ngFor` then try to compile it's a tedious process that reason I don't think anybody can help you here.

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of *ng* in templates so it's hard to find one, that throws error. But in my case error was in `(change)`. I use self-made directive, which allows to define variable in template and in that `(change)` I tried to change its value. Something like `(change)= "myTemplateVariable = someValue"`

Answer (score 0):

In my case `[(ngValue)]` was use instead of `[ngValue]`